# Average Row [SQL]

Tags: sql, row, average

Actually I'm a bit confused about what should i wrote in the subject.

The point is like this, I want to average the `Speed01,Speed02,Speed03` and `Speed04` :

```
SELECT
   Table01.Test_No,
   Table01.Speed01,
   Table01.Speed02,
   Table01.Speed03,
   Table01.Speed04,
```

I want to create new column that consists of this average -->>

```
AVG(Table01.Speed01, Table01.Speed02, Table01.Speed03,Table01.Speed04) as "Average"
```

I have tried this, but it did not work.

```
From
   Table01
```

So, the contain of the Speed column could be exist but sometimes the Speed02 don't have number but the others are have numbers. sometimes speed04 data is also missing and the others is exist, sometimes only one data (example: only Speed01) have the data. lets say it depends on the sensor ability to catch the speed of the test material.

It will be a big help if you can find the solution. I'm newbie here.
THANK YOU ^^

Answer (score 1):

`AVG` is a SQL aggregate function, therefore not applicable. So simply do the math. Average is sum divided by count:

```
(SPEED01 + SPEED02 + SPEED03 +SPEED04)/4
```

To deal with missing values, use NULLIF or COALESCE:

```
(COALESCE(SPEED01, 0) + COALESCE(SPEED02, 0) + COALESCE(SPEED03, 0) + COALESCE(SPEED04, 0))
```

That leaves the denominator. You need to add 1 for every non null. For example:

```
(COALESCE(SPEED01/SPEED01,0) + COALESCE(SPEED02/SPEED02,0) + ...)
```

You can also use CASE, depending on the supported SQL dialect, to avoid the possible divide by 0:

```
CASE WHEN SPEED01 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1
```

**OR** you can normalize the data, extract all SPEEDs into a 1:M relation and use the `AVG` aggregate, avoiding all these issues. Not to mention the possibility to add a 5th measurement, then a 6th and so on and so forth!

Comment: well, actually i dont know about "normalize the data" what is it suppose to be? what kind of operation is it? and is it really necessary to to that?

Comment: Normalize means you store each SPEED as a row in a new table. then you can add as many SPEED values as you want for each measurement. Read more ad [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the columns and divide them by 4. To deal with the "missing" values use `coalesce` to treat `NULL` values as zero:

```
SELECT Test_No,
      (coalesce(Speed01,0) + coalesce(Speed02,0) + coalesce(Speed03,0) + coalesce(Speed04,0)) / 4 as "Average"
FROM Table01;
```

You didn't mention your DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, ...), but the above is ANSI (standard) SQL and should run on nearly every DBMS.

Comment: You need to adjust the denominator too for NULLs.

Comment: im using ORACLE, i have try yours, somehow it did not work. it said something like this --> Execute Fail.
[Info] CreateADORecordset Error
[Info] ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @RemusRusanu: You are right. But depends on how NULLs should be treated. If the conversion to zero is OK, then it's not necessary to change it.

Comment: @EkynaldiEky: sorry I had two `AS` keywords. I fixed it (btw: you could have noticed that yourself. Don't just blindly run statements from the internet, think about what they do)

Comment: ah sorry, actually i notice that double `AS`. i thought it is necessary to put double `AS` well my bad, i need to learn more about this. Thank you so much for the help! ^^

Comment: True, it depends on the actual desired semantics. But I somehow doubt that if your hardware captured only one SPEED in 4 attempts then the average is SPEED/4.

Comment: Guys, actually i just noticed this today, the script above is right but i think when the data in the speed01 is not exist, it turn to be 0 right? so for example, when the speed01 = 20, speed02 = 25 and the other speed column has no data, the average should be divided by 2, the result should show 22,5. but with the above script shows the result 11.25. So, to make the result 22,5. what am i suppose to do?

Comment: @EkynaldiEky: see Remus' answer

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, I supposed that `Table01.Speed01`, `Table01.Speed03`, `Table01.Speed04` are nullable and of type `int` whereas `Table01.Speed02` is nullable and of type `nvarchar`:

```
SELECT
    Table01.Test_No,
    (
        ISNULL(Table01.Speed01, 0) + 
        CASE ISNUMERIC(Table01.Speed02) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(Table01.Speed02 AS int) END +
        ISNULL(Table01.Speed03, 0) + 
        ISNULL(Table01.Speed04, 0)
    )/4 AS AVG
FROM Table01
```

Comment: Nice answer! Please note that code blocks can be generated by adding four lines in front of every line, as in the edit I suggested on your post.

Comment: i still can't understand why this you use different function here `CASE ISNUMERIC(Table01.Speed02) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(Table01.Speed02 AS int) END`

Comment: You said in your question that "sometimes the Speed02 don't have number", so I assumed that Speed02 is column of type varchar, so definitely we need to check if it contains number then it will be included in average formula otherwise, it will excluded.